# Is it good idea to use business key for relation and findBy method?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Sometimes we have some unique fields in the `Spring Data JPA` entities e.g. `iban` field. As these fields are unique and not nullable, normally we can use these fields for creating relationship between two tables. However, these fields are not numeric field, it may not be suitable for creating relation as the id fields. In this situation, it may be better to use id fields for relation between tables. So, which approach is better?

On the other hand, when there is a unique field annotated by `@NaturalId` and we need to search by using this field e.g. `findByCode(String code)`, then is it enough simply adding a method to the related Repository as shown below:

```
Optional<Product> findByCode(String code);
```

Or should we make such an implementation shown in the following example?

[How to Use Hibernate Natural IDs in Spring Boot](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-use-hibernate-natural-ids-in-spring-boot)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For considering a field as primary key (and thereby as base for a foreign key relationship), its type doesn't matter too much if it's a simple type like numeric values or string.

My primary reason for not using a business key as a primary key is that you hardly can predict the future on how stable such a key is. I'm not sure about the regulations for ibans, but it might be that at some point in the future all possible ibans with the existing format are utilized - and it's decided to either reuse old ones or change their format.

Depending on how strictly your database depends on the data format of such a business key, this might break your schema, e.g., when suddenly the uniqueness is violated or the new data format doesn't match your primary key column definition anymore. Especially getting primary keys migrated when they are used as foreign keys in relationships is a pain.

Therefore, I'd always try to avoid business keys as primary keys in databases and rather use arbitrary technical keys which are entirely under your control.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Hibernate's `@NaturalId`. Just from quickly [reading](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/mappingGuide/en-US/html/ch07.html) up on it, I guess it's a simplification which can also be achieved by setting up a unique index on the respective field. From a quick search I don't see Spring Data supports `@NaturalId`. Therefore, I would rather refrain from using `@NaturalId` and simply work on Spring Data's level of abstraction instead of switching forth and back between Spring Data and Hibernate.